# alter the appearance of iframe content within a phonegap android apps

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

i have a app load a iframe with remote url to a div

```
$('#page_dashboard').live('pageshow', function(){
      $('<iframe>', {
        src: 'http://mydomain/interview_apps_front_poll/',
        id:  'myFrame',
        frameborder: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        scrolling: 'yes'
      }).appendTo('#interview_apps_front_poll');
});
```

is it possible to alter the appearance of the content of the iframe by using js or css on android phonegap coding side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page in the iframe is yours then yes, with some webservices. If not, then no.

If it is yours, you could alter the html in the iframe if your app posted a message to a web-service (service A), service A then stores the data on your server, and the page in the iframe called another service (service B) on your server every 15 seconds or so to check for new data on the server that was placed there by service A. Very round about way to do it but browser security sandbox's iframe's pretty well.